# HTML - what does it mean when it says an attribute can have a string datatype as its value in laymans terms?

Tags: html, string

I was wondering what does a string datatype value for an attribute mean. does it mean I can use letters and number for the attributes value? What are its restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

A string is usually just any "string" of characters (numbers, letters, symbols, etc).  In the context of HTML and attributes specifically, I recommend checking out this w3c page:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html

Note that there are different restrictions if the attribute is unquoted, single quoted, or double quoted.